# HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler failed authenticating service on Cas 4.2.3

Tags: validation, service, single-sign-on, cas

I'm having problem with cas 4.2.3. My custom login flow has run thoroughly, but at the service validation step, i don't know why cas server try to connect to app server and then i got the connect timed out exception.
My Org's network policy requires that some apps (http or https) may just has one way connection to cas server (i don't know why).

Here are the log:

```
2016-08-30 09:28:52,901 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter] - <Sending external redirect to 'http://10.149.91.118:8100/?ticket=ST-1-pz6FgAczf1tcIMbuYUab-id.....vn'> 2016-08-30 09:28:52,901 DEBUG [org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter] - <Sending external redirect to 'http://10.149.91.118:8100/?ticket=ST-1-pz6FgAczf1tcIMbuYUab-id.....vn'> 2016-08-30 09:28:58,121 ERROR [org.jasig.cas.util.http.SimpleHttpClient] - <Connect to
10.149.91.118:8100 [/10.149.91.118] failed: connect timed out org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to
10.149.91.118:8100 [/10.149.91.118] failed: connect timed out   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:143) ...

2016-08-30 09:28:58,124 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager] - <HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler failed authenticating http://10.149.91.118:8100/?proxyResponse=true> 2016-08-30 09:28:58,131 WARN [org.jasig.cas.web.ProxyValidateController] - <Failed to authenticate service credential http://10.149.91.118:8100/?proxyResponse=true>
```

How can i customize the service validation to skip this or would someone guide me another way to make it works.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your validation step? Is it validate? serviceValidate? proxyValidate? What are the parameters?

Comment: On the log, i saw it transitioned through all the login states until Sending external redirect to redirect back to the client, the exception logged right after that. I think it's when the client received the generated ticket and it calls back to Cas Server to validate that ticket. I didn't config it to use proxyValidate but i don't know why it execute PolicyBasedAuthenticationManager. Sorry, I couldn't find parameters on the log.